# mariadb sql default unix_timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, migration, create-table

I have troubles with changing column in table from timestamp type to integer (unix). To both queries below mysql don't let me execute them with the error 1064: "... error in SQL syntax..." and my sql editor (MYSQL WORKBENCH) highlights with red the UNIX_TIMESTAMP func right after default and says: `"UNIX_TIMESTAMP" is not valid at this position, expecting: DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIME, INT number, LONG number, UNLONGLONG number, ...`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
ALTER TABLE `lamourka`.`profile` CHANGE `updated_at` `updated_at` 
int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

ALTER TABLE `lamourka`.`profile` MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` 
    int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

[image: pic]

I'm using MariaDB. SELECT VERSION(): 10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~bionic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not allow using functions to set defaults.

I would recommend using the `TIMESTAMP` datatype. You can them retrieve the values in second using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oFgDSQpnpgY8RpDDmhK8ad/0)**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id int, updated_at date);
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY column updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

INSERT INTO mytable(id) values(1);
SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at) updated_at FROM mytable;

| id  | updated_at |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | 1570695109 |
```

The other option is to keep the column datatype as an integer but then manually call  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` on each insert.